# Intermediate table with generic foreign key

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to replace a field in an intermediate table with a generic field. Using Django 1.6, MariaDB/MySQL.

I have a class (PermissionGroup) that links a resource to a group. Works fine. However I have several other tables that are similar - linking some id to a group id.

I thought I could replace these tables with one table that uses a generic foreign key, along with the group id. However this does not validate.

Here's the original, which works:

```
# core/models.py
    class PermissionGroup(models.Model):
        resource = models.ForeignKey('core.Resource')
        group = models.ForeignKey('auth.Group')

    class Resource(models.Model):
        groups = models.ManyToManyField('auth.Group', through='core.PermissionGroup')


# auth/models.py
    class Group(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
```

Now, trying to change the PermissionGroup to use a GenericForeignKey:

```
# core/models.py
    class PermissionGroup(models.Model):
        content_type = models.ForeignKey('contenttypes.ContentType')
        object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
        group = models.ForeignKey('auth.Group')

    class Resource(models.Model):
        groups = models.ManyToManyField('auth.Group', through='core.PermissionGroup')

# auth/models.py
    class Group(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
```

The django model validation now fails with:

core.resource: 'groups' is a manually-defined m2m relation through model PermissionGroup, which does not have foreign keys to Group and Resource

Is this simply not possible, or is another means to accomplish this?